# consistent unicode mobile browser support?

Tags: android, html, unicode, mobile-browser

Im developing my first mobile website and i just found out that this "three lines" Unicode `&#9776`; wasn´t working on my samsung galaxy s2 so i updated that for this unicode `&#x2261`;
My question is if there´s a way to ensure that the three lines shows up in every mobile browser using unicode? or should i upload a icon or images instead for the three lines?
i dont know if this has anything to do but this is the div containing the unicode

```
<div id="uni">
    <a id="menu_bar" href="">
        <p>&#x2261; &#9776;</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Unify, a table that lists Unicode support across browsers and devices](http://unicode.johnholtripley.co.uk/), [U+2630 has 58% overall support](http://unicode.johnholtripley.co.uk/2630/) while [U+2261 has 96% overall support](http://unicode.johnholtripley.co.uk/2261/).

> My question is if there’s a way to ensure that the three lines shows up in every mobile browser using unicode?

It depends on the mobile browsers you want to support. Given the abovementioned info, U+2261 is probably good enough, but if you need full support in modern browsers, consider using icon fonts or SVG images instead.